# x86-64: int 0x80 will not print from memory

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-64

Apologies for the poorly worded question, but this has been puzzling me.

To demonstrate what I am trying to convey, here's an example program:

```
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
dec rsp
mov rcx,rsp
mov al,"c"
mov [rcx],al
mov rax,4
mov rdx,1
mov rbx,1
int 0x80
leave
ret
```

However, when compiled and executed, linux does not print anything to the terminal, when it is expected to print "c"

Is there something i'm missing?

Comment: What language are you writing?  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: `rsp` is outside the low 32 bits of virtual address space, so truncating it (by using the 32-bit `int 0x80` ABI) results in a `-EFAULT` error return from the system call.